# importing excel to sqlite in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am making an application in Ruby on Rails which will ask users multiple choice questions. I want to upload questions to the database from an excel file. How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save the Excel spreadsheet as a CSV file then use a CSV parser, perhaps in a rake file:

In lib/taks/import.rake:

```
require 'fastercsv'
namespace :import => :environment do
   task :questions do
     FasterCSV.foreach("path/to/file.csv") do |row|
           q = Question.create(:question=>row[0], etc...)
           PossibleAnswer.create(:question=>q, :answer=>row[1], etc....) #providing PossibleAnswer belongs_to Question
      end
   end 
end
```

Then run "rake import:questions"

Comment: thanks for the answer...i am new to RoR. can u tell what the model should be like to use this rake file...

Comment: It could work with any model, just replace the bit in parenthesis with your field names

Comment: I'm getting uninitialized constant Question on rake import:questions

Comment: apologies, forgot to include environment, Amended response

Answer (score 1):

You could use the spreadsheet gem to read in the data from an excel file:
http://rubygems.org/gems/spreadsheet

This is most useful if you want to allow users to upload their own excel documents, to import some questions, or if you want users to be able to download questions in excel file format.

If you just want to do a one-off import of some data i would go with Yule's idea and just do it via csv which is much easier to get to grips with.

Comment: I have installed this gem but dont know how to use it and i cant find any tutorial on it.

Comment: It's actually pretty well documented, ie has a good rdoc.  The best way i find to read these is to start a gem server and view it in a browser.  `gem server` in the console, then go to `localhost:8808` in a browser, click 'spreadsheet' then 'rdoc'.  The GUIDE link has a lot of useful examples.